# Install ubuntu over ubuntu server (boot on usb device from ubuntu server)

Tags: boot, server, system-installation, usb

I just installed Ubuntu server on my PC but I wanted to install Ubuntu desktop. I created a bootable USB with Ubuntu 22.04 but when I press <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd> there is no option to boot on the USB device.

Do you know how can I boot on a USB device from Ubuntu server ?

Comment: You can chose "Enter UEFI setup" or something like that from the GRUB boot menu if your GRUB version is the UEFI one ... But, alternatively, you can just do `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` on the already installed server itself, then you should have the desktop version without needing to use any boot media or reinstalling the OS and without loosing your current user data as well.

Comment: I have only 2 choices : ubuntu and ubuntu recovery mode from the GRUB.

Comment: Then that means your GRUB is installed in legacy BIOS mode ... The options to enter BIOS boot menu/settings are hardware specific and you can find them in your computer's user's manual and have nothing to do with Ubuntu or any other OS for that matter.

Comment: BIOS/UEFI selection is before GRUB. If you see GRUB, you missed it. Reboot and try again.